# Transposition Cipher in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

Im currently trying to code a transposition cipher in python. however i have reached a point where im stuck.

my code:

```
key = "german"
length = len(key)
plaintext = "if your happy and you know it clap your hands, clap your hands"
Formatted = "".join(plaintext.split()).replace(",","")
split = split_text(formatted,length)

def split_text(formatted,length):
return [formatted[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(formatted), length)]

def encrypt():
```

i use that to count the length of the string, i then use the length to determine how many columns to create within the program. So it would create this:

```
GERMAN
IFYOUR
HAPPYA
NDYOUK
NOWITC
LAPYOU
RHANDS
CLAPYO
URHAND
S
```

this is know where im stuck. as i want to get the program to create a string by combining the columns together. so it would combine each column to create:

```
IHNNLRCUSFADOAHLRYPYWPAAH .....
```

i know i would need a loop of some sort but unsure how i would tell the program to create such a string.

thanks

Comment: What is your question? Is the `IHNNLRCU...` after it has gone through encryption?

Comment: Yes its the outcome after the encryption

Answer (score 1):

you can use slices of the string to get each letter of the string in steps of 6 (length)

```
print(formatted[0::length])
#output:
ihnnlrcus
```

Then just loop through all the possible start indices in `range(length)` and link them all together:

```
def encrypt(formatted,length):
    return "".join([formatted[i::length] for i in range(length)])
```

note that this doesn't actually use `split_text`, it would take `formatted` directly:

```
print(encrypt(formatted,length))
```

the problem with using the `split_text` you then cannot make use of tools like `zip` since they stop when the first iterator stops (so because the last group only has one character in it you only get the one group from `zip(*split)`)

```
for i in zip("stuff that is important","a"):
    print(i)

#output:
("s","a")
#nothing else, since one of the iterators finished.
```

In order to use something like that you would have to redefine the way zip works by allowing some of the iterators to finish and continue until all of them are done:

```
def myzip(*iterators):
    iterators = tuple(iter(it) for it in iterators)
    while True: #broken when none of iterators still have items in them
        group = []
        for it in iterators:
            try:
                group.append(next(it))
            except StopIteration:
                pass
        if group:
            yield group
        else:
            return #none of the iterators still had items in them
```

then you can use this to process the split up data like this:

```
encrypted_data = ''.join(''.join(x) for x in myzip(*split))
```